# Unable to use any windows drives in WSL

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I was tiring to access files inside `/mnt` in WSL(Ubuntu). But when I typed `ls ./d` it gave the following error:

```
ls: cannot open directory '.': Input/output error
```

This is happening while using any command in any file of the windows drives, I also typed `cd ./d/<any-folder>` and it gave the following:

```
cd: Input/output error: <folder-name>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand as to why I was getting that error.
But try restarting your device.
It worked for me.

Comment: Restarting worked for me too.   In my case, I suspect it was caused by the installation of Docker (which uses WSL2 behind the scenes).

Comment: I also had the same issue after uninstalling Docker Desktop, restarting was sufficient.

Answer (score 7):

As pointed [here](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4377), just go to the PowerShell and run the command `wsl.exe --shutdown` and restart the WSL.